# Change Type and Format of date while preserving display

Tags: date, types, format, stata

I'm trying to destring a type str9 / %9s date variable in my dataset that is in the form DDMonYYYY (where Mon is a three letter month abbreviation), and I would like to keep it in its current form.

I have been performing an `egen newvarname = max(date)` on other datasets I have where the date comes in Type: int, Format: %td, and I would like to be able to convert the dates in the datasets with dates as strings to the same type and format, while preserving the form, so I can do that same command.

Comment: You will go further on StackOverflow if you provide some sort of attempt at a solution and indicate what you have tried already.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and always provide a [mcve] using the `dataex` command in Stata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advisable working with dates that are of type string. It is always best if you convert your date variables from string to numeric.

In order to do so, you need to use the `daily()` function as opposed to the `destring` or `encode` commands (for a discussion of the inappropriateness of the latter see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987980/)).

For example:

```
clear
set obs 2

generate date_string = ""
replace date_string = "29Oct2012" in 1
replace date_string = "14Jan2015" in 2

generate date_numeric = daily(date_string, "DMY")
list, abbreviate(20) noobs

  +----------------------------+
  | date_string   date_numeric |
  |----------------------------|
  |   29Oct2012          19295 |
  |   14Jan2015          20102 |
  +----------------------------+

format %tdDDMonCCYY date_numeric
list, abbreviate(20) noobs

  +----------------------------+
  | date_string   date_numeric |
  |----------------------------|
  |   29Oct2012      29Oct2012 |
  |   14Jan2015      14Jan2015 |
  +----------------------------+
```

You could then use `egen` as desired:

```
egen date_max = max(date_numeric)
format %tdDDMonCCYY date_max
list, abbreviate(20) noobs

  +----------------------------------------+
  | date_string   date_numeric    date_max |
  |----------------------------------------|
  |   29Oct2012      29Oct2012   14Jan2015 |
  |   14Jan2015      14Jan2015   14Jan2015 |
  +----------------------------------------+
```

If you insist on having everything as string, you can use afterwards the `tostring` command:

```
tostring date_max date_numeric, replace format("%tdddMonCCYY") force
```

Comment: Wonderful. I wanted it all in numeric so this is perfect. Thank you for the help!